# RewriteRule not catching

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to redirect index.php?page=11. (with the period) to index.php?page=11 (no period). This is a page that somehow was indexed in Google, that breaks with the period in the URL.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?page\=11\.$ index.php?page=11 [R=301]
```

This is not catching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the `?`) in a rewrite rule, you need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=11\.$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?page=11 [L,R=301]
```